# voice to sign language translation

Tags: android

i am using two activities in my program.In first activity i done coding of voice to text and in second activity i done coding for text to sign langauge i linked it through button.but it doesn't move to another activity.I want this that the textveiw of voice recongnition to be shown on another activity.Please help

fist java code of voice recongnizer

```
package com.authorwjf.talk2me;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    protected static final int REQUEST_OK = 1;
    public static String EXTRA_MESSAGE;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
         i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
         try {
             startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_OK);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Error initializing speech to text engine.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==REQUEST_OK  && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> thingsYouSaid = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(thingsYouSaid.get(0));
        }
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

this is xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
        android:text="..." />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Enter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my second activity

```
package com.authorwjf.talk2me;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Second extends Activity {

    // View Objects
        Button translate;
        EditText enterText;
        TextView displayText;
        ImageView aslImages;
        MediaPlayer mP;
        Second thisClass;
        // Variables for Translation and Display
        int phraseIndex = 0; // Keep track of the array indexes
        String letters; // Message to be Translated
        String display; // Will hold the letters already displayed and show them
        String PhraseIndex;
        // Array Libraries For Characters and Image References
        String letterIndex[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j",
                "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w",
                "x", "y", "z", "hello", "hi", "happy", "sad", "dad", "mom", "school", " " };

        int aslPics[] = { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d,
                R.drawable.e, R.drawable.f, R.drawable.g, R.drawable.h,
                R.drawable.i, R.drawable.j, R.drawable.k, R.drawable.l,
                R.drawable.m, R.drawable.n, R.drawable.o, R.drawable.p,
                R.drawable.q, R.drawable.r, R.drawable.s, R.drawable.t,
                R.drawable.u, R.drawable.v, R.drawable.w, R.drawable.x,
                R.drawable.y, R.drawable.z, R.drawable.hello, R.drawable.happy, R.drawable.sad,
                R.drawable.dad, R.drawable.mom, R.drawable.school, R.drawable.space };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            thisClass = this;
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            setupActionBar();
             // Get the message from the intent
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

            // Create the text view
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTextSize(40);
            textView.setText(message);

            // Set the text view as the activity layout
            setContentView(textView);

            // Attach objects to view objects
            translate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTranslate);
            translate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setString(v);
                    translateLetter();
                }
            });
            enterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textInput);
            displayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayText);
            aslImages = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.aslViewer);
            aslImages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    translateLetter();
                }
            });

            // Select all the Text in the enterText Field
            enterText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
        }

        // setString Function
        // Acts when the Translate Button is pressed
        public void setString(View v) {
            // Set the text of displayText to'--- '"
            displayText.setText("   ----");


            // Reset the Phrase Index
            phraseIndex = 0;
            display = "";

            // Get the Input Text
            String phrase = enterText.getText().toString();
            letters = phrase.toLowerCase();
        }

        // Displays Image when ImageView Touched.
        // Also displays text of letters already translated

        public void translateLetter() {
            // Checks if letters string is null-displays message
            // If the phrase has not been converted to a string
            if (letters == null) {
                displayText.setText("Press the Translate Button ");
            }

            // Checks if letters string is null-will not display
            // ASL letters until translate Button is pressed
            if (letters != null) {
                // Fetch the current Character in the phrase
                String currentLetter = letters;

                // add the letter to the display string
                display += currentLetter;

                // Search for the corresponding ASL image by Index
                for (int i = 0; i < letterIndex.length; i++) {
                    if (letterIndex[i].contentEquals(currentLetter)) {
                        // Display the image
                        aslImages.setImageResource(aslPics[i]);
                    } // end if
                }// end for
                    // Set the text to display the letters translated
                displayText.setText("   " + display);
                // Advance to the Next Letter in the Phrase
                phraseIndex++;

                // Check to see if you reach the end of the phrase
                if (phraseIndex > letters.length() - 1) {
                    // Reset back to the first character
                    phraseIndex = 0;
                    display = "";
                } // end if
            }// end Function translateLetter()
        }// end if

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        /**
         * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
         */
        private void setupActionBar() {

            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        }



        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
                // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
                // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
                // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
                //
                // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
                //
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

}
```

this is second xml file

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/aslViewer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:onClick="translateletter"
            android:contentDescription="@string/hand_images"
            android:src="@drawable/a" />

    </TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:text="@string/T_text"/>
    </TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTranslate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:onClick="setString"
       android:text="@string/Translate"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Enter_Text" >

    </EditText>

</TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

this menifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.authorwjf.talk2me"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.authorwjf.talk2me.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.authorwjf.talk2me.Second"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.authorwjf.talk2me.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.authorwjf.talk2me.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to call `sendMessage(View view)` on button click.
add `android:onClick="sendMessage"` for button2.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Enter"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

Also, for safty check for button1,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.button1){
        //Your code
     }
}
```

Inside second activity, I don't think the use of `setContentView(textView);` is correct. You may get NullPointerException after this line. I think a 'Toast' is enough. Or declare TextView inside xml instead of dynamic creation.

Comment: i did correction in my code as you told but it not workin when i click button it shows unfortunately the app has been stoped and i also delete the textview from code and add it to xml please tell.

Comment: Are you aware of using Logcat? It will give you a clear idea about the error.